# Lenovo T440P Ubuntu 14.04 compatibility?

Tags: 14.04, lenovo

Have anyone had any luck with installing a clean copy of Ubuntu 14.04 on a Lenovo T440P (I have NVidia 730m on it, FYI)? My screen wouldn't even come past the language chooser a month ago, so I was wondering if anyone had any luck with it now?

I tried upgrading 13.10 to 14.04 which worked fine... If! I switched from kernel 3.13 to 3.11, but that kinda defeats the purpose.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had multiple problems with installing ubuntu/xubuntu 14.04 on this laptop (Thinkpad t440p gt730m).

I was able to install ubunut/xubuntu by adding option `nomodeset` to install option - see example link: [How to set nomodeset GRUB2 before I've installed Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431534/how-to-set-nomodeset-grub2-before-ive-installed-ubuntu)
Unfortunately, after boot I wasn't able to use graphics properly (drivers were unable to load). Finally I found that there's problem with BIOS which may even lead to data corruption, example link - https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch/issues/78
So I decided to downgrade my BIOS to version 1.14, which is last known to be working properly BIOS version. After flashing BIOS (you will find instruction in link above), Ubuntu 14.04 installed without any issue, and 3D acceleration was enabled out of the box. I decided though to install nvidia prioprietary drivers (using simple 'additional drivers' utility) and now everything works like a charm (even ultra dock station :D) - I'm using nvidia-prime to switch graphics.

Hope lenovo fixes the BIOS problem in next version!

Good luck!

edit: After downgrading BIOS, Ubuntu will boot/install without editing boot options (that is, you don't need to add `nomodeset` option anymore)