# install ubuntu on thinkpad T440p

Tags: system-installation, thinkpad

Is there anybody, who is able to install and fully configure Ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04 on Thinkpad T440p (ver 20AN)? If yes, could you post here your procedure step by step?

Please does not include your experience with any other ThinkPad models.

Edit: Situation is not so simple, see: [Lenovo ThinkPad T440p + Ubuntu 12.04/14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454268/lenovo-thinkpad-t440p-ubuntu-12-04-14-04)

Comment: What's wrong with it? Linux supports many computers like yours out there. Have you tried it?

Comment: @karel does he have problems installing it?

Comment: @owl Yes, according to his Edit:

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of problem with installation (especially NVIDIA optimus). With Ubuntu 14.04 system hangon during install image booting.

Comment: Why are you asking two almost identical questions?

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely been proven that Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS 64-bit will work on your device. Please check this link for more details:

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201307-13930/

As mentioned, check out this guide of how to install Ubuntu: [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: The Lenovo certification is a kind of joke, because there is no viable way how to install nvidia optimus driver, for example.

Comment: @michal I have a few machines that has Nvidia Optimus graphics cards and they seem to work fine on Ubuntu. I believe that some support is already given to such graphics cards. Check out: http://zeronteproject.com/74/ for information about it.

Comment: There is a plenty of notebooks with NVIDIA Optimus, which works fine on Ubuntu 12.04/14.04. But I am asking specifically for ThinkPad T440p. On this notebook is not possible to apply standard configuration processes.

Answer (score 0):

for me installing Ubuntu 14.4 on a lenovo t440p worked after I followed the instructions found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454268/lenovo-thinkpad-t440p-ubuntu-12-04-14-04)

> I had the same problem with my T440p i7-4700MQ with Intel and Nvidia.
>
> I managed to finally boot off a 14.04 Live-DVD by pressing F6 and/or ESC as 
>   soon as the "Press Enter" disappeared. Then I modified the boot options to "nomodeset"
>   which led me to the choice between "try ..." and "install ...". I went for "try..."
>   and once the desktop showed up from where I then installed Trusty 64bit.
>
> It goes without saying that the boot options in grub are set to nomodeset, but at 
>   least the notebook is working. WLAN is ok. I reach speeds up to 780 MBit/s. There 
>   remain several issues though: display brightness buttons are not functional, 
>   fingerprint reader is not detected, and the proprietary nvidia driver is something 
>   that will maybe work properly some day.

Note that, at least with my lenovo 440p, you need to press Fn+F6 instead of just F6 to enter the Boot Options. See [BootOptions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions) for a description of the menue in which you get after pressing Fn+F6.

If you follow the link above, you should also find instructions on how to install Nvidia Prime. I haven't tried so far.

Finally, I used an USB stick instead of a DVD.

Answer (score 0):

I had many problems with installing Ubuntu/Xubuntu untill I downgraded BIOS to 1.14 version - 
please see my answer for details - [Lenovo T440P Ubuntu 14.04 compatibility?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484410/lenovo-t440p-ubuntu-14-04-compatibility) .
Just to let you know: I was able to install Ubuntu by adding `nomodeset` option, but graphics card drivers couldn't be load (`lshw` result shows displays as UNCLAIMED). 
That cause no 3D acceleration support, no function keys working (to set screen brightness), external displays not working (with ultra dock station), etc. etc.

After downgrading BIOS everything seems to be working perfectly well.

Wish you luck!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to post to your shared link (but don't have enough rep to answer) since it is the top google result for this laptops's 14.04 Ubuntu issues. Nevertheless, for my t440p, fwiw 14.10 desktop 64-bit worked flawlessly (see caveat below), I downloaded updates during install, installed the nvidia proprietary drivers ("updates" version) after login, and was able to launch CS: Source as a test. This is miraculous compared to the constant freezes that would occur in 14.04, requiring a hard shutdown.

Not sure what model you have, but I have the 20ANCTO1WW (4800MQ, 730M, 8GB RAM, 500GB HDD). After spending nearly an entire evening attempting to figure out how to get around the issues with this thing and 14.04 I gave up and just tried 14.10. Lenovo's website says that >= 2.26 BIOS cannot be downgraded (I have 2.28, having recently ordered the laptop). So the downgrade to 1.14 was not an option for me.

So, if you're not married to 14.04, try 14.10 and see if it works for you. Caveat: I could not get sound to work, however, it did not work in Windows either, so I'm fairly certain it's a hardware issue.

Hope that helps!

Best regards,
J