# Black screen after installation window

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, uefi

So I wanted to try out Ubuntu (I have only worked with Windows so far), but all I get after the installation window is a black screen.

Here's the detailed description. I currently have Windows 10 installed and want to install Ubuntu as well (as dual-boot), so I shrinked one of the partitions of my hard-drive, downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS from the Ubuntu-Website and burned the ISO on a DVD (using the Windows 10 tool via the context-menu → burn). Then I rebooted the computer, but it booted Windows again. So I restarted again and entered the ASUS UEFI BIOS utility. In the Boot Priority section, there were three items in the following order:

1. P1: ATAPI iHAS124 F
2. P2: WDC WD20EZRX-00D8PB0
3. UEFI: ATAPI iHAS124 F

(BTW, Windows is installed on an SSD which doesn't show up in this section at all, yet Windows starts up normally - curious)

So I switched the order of the items 2. & 3. and rebooted again. This time, I saw this loading screen:

[image: ubuntu loading screen]

But after a few seconds, it went away, I briefly saw the blinking vertical cursor and then some other text flash up on the upper left side of the screen, then got a black screen again (my monitor said `no signal detected`).
So I googled a bit and found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) and pressed the <kbd>↓</kbd> key while the loading screen was visible, which gave me this menu:

[image: ubuntu start menu]

Following the instructions in the thread linked above, I tried setting the `nomodeset` option (and later the `acpi=off` and `nolapic` options as well), but still after I clicked `Try Ubuntu without installing` my monitor got no signal.

I have two monitors, one is connected via HDMI, the other via DVI, both to my GPU (MSI GTX 970 Gaming 4G). The menues described above appeared on the one connected via DVI, while the other one got no signal. My CPU is an Intel Xeon E3-1231 which has no built-in graphics unit, so I can't connect the monitors directly to the mainboard's VGA/DVI ports. My mainboard is an ASUS B85-Pro Gamer.

So, can anyone help me? What can I do to troubleshoot this problem? As I mentioned, I'm new to Linux, so I don't have any experience and I'm also not familiar with the different boot options (UEFI/BIOS et c.). If you need any additional information (e.g. about my hardware), let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to install via UEFI and then select Install UBUNTU GNOME, and then press 'e' and between quiet and splash insert `nomodeset`.

For reference, please see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431534/how-to-set-nomodeset-grub2-before-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Comment: To answer your unstated questions about booting with nomodeset, please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/128137/283721)

Comment: I saw these topics, but SHIFT doesn't work for me...

Comment: Assuming that you can get Ubuntu loaded, inserting `nomodeset` into the grub config file does not require the use of SHIFT.  If you are having problems with boot, then the application of SHIFT is a timing dependent thing.