# Ubuntu installation 16.04.2 LTS Display Not Working

Tags: boot, 16.04, nvidia, uefi, usb-installation

It all started when I changed my AMD graphic cards to GTX.

So I have a problem with Ubuntu, it happened before but I managed to install it through LEGACY version but not UEFI (With `nomodeset` only that way).

So now I need to install Ubuntu UEFI, because I want dual-boot Ubuntu/Windows.

Again, when I press in the menu "Install UBUNTU" my both monitors (both connected to GPU one is DP and other is VGA) just goes OFF SIGNAL and I can't do a thing just force OFF computer by pressing and holding power button.

My PC (if it helps):

- GTX 970
- I5-4430
- 8GB RAM
- h81m-k

ALSO, I've tried to turning off Secure Boot and Fast Boot.

Thanks for answers!

P.S. Main OS is Windows 10

AFTER FIX (SORRY FOR DUPLICATE)

So after I install ubuntu, when I press RESTART NOW after installation, my computer restarts, but when I select UBUNTU in a boot menu, it just goes to sleep, NO SIGNAL again, is it possible to set `nomodeset` before it goes to Sleep while booting into OS ? I hope you guys understood the question.

NOTE: I deleted Windows 10. So it's only ubuntu on my SSD.

Comment: Have you tried setting `nomodeset` in grub? https://askubuntu.com/questions/431534/how-to-set-nomodeset-grub2-before-ive-installed-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for answer, no I didn't, I'm gonna to try !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Organic Marble!

I inserted nomodeset in GRUB and it worked !